# why does my go channel get blocked ? (deadlock)

Tags: concurrency, go

It seems that the "complex" (`getC`) function is blocked. I assume the channel is destroyed once it is read therefore I'm wondering how can I share the `sC` channel with both `getC` function and the `main` function without  get into deadlock ( [current snippet](http://play.golang.org/p/WnENKTFCtm) )

```
package main

func main() {

//simple function and complex function/channel

    sC := make(chan string)
    go getS(sC)

    cC := make(chan string)
    go getC(sC, cC)

//collect the functions result 

        s := <-sC
//do something with `s`. We print but we may want to use it in a `func(s)`
print(s)
//after a while we do soemthing with `c`
        c := <-cC


    print(c)
}

func getS(sC chan string) {
    s :=  " simple completed "
    sC <- s
}

func getC(sC chan string, cC chan string) {
//we do some complex stuff
  print("complex is not complicated\n")
//Now  we need the simple value so we try wait for the s channel.
    s := <-sC

    c := s + " more "
    cC <- c //send complex value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to get value from `sC` channel in main function because the only value you send to it is  consumed by `getC` function in seperate go routine. While trying to read `sC` channel main function blocks waiting for something and it never ends. Go routine `getS` is finished, go routine `getC` has consumed value from channel `sC` and has also finished. There is nothing in channel `sC` anymore.

The possible solution is to create another channel `s2C` and send to it value received from `sC` channel.

The complete correct code would look like this:

```
package main

func main() {
    sC := make(chan string)
    go getS(sC)

    s2C := make(chan string)
    cC := make(chan string)
    go getC(s2C, cC)

    s := <-sC
    println(s)
    s2C <- s

    c := <-cC
    println(c)
}

func getS(sC chan string) {
    s :=  " simple completed "
    sC <- s
}

func getC(sC chan string, cC chan string) {
    s := <-sC
    c := s + " more "
    cC <- c
}
```

Comment: but I need the "s" value in main so that I can run another go routine using it. Should I open a duplicate sC channel    ?

Comment: @Theuserwithnohat I don't understand your statement. Do you want to send one value to the channel and read it twice from the channel?

Comment: pretty much that's the case . I need to print ``s`` in the ``main`` function but ``getC`` also needs it to construct ``c``.

Comment: I'm not sure if the question was unclear but it seems the answer was quite obvious (after a while).

Answer (score 0):

I should have sent s from getS. Code below

```
package main

import "time"

func main() {

    //simple function and complex function/channel
    sC := make(chan string)
    go getS(sC)

    cC := make(chan string)
    go getC(sC, cC)

    //collect the functions result

    s := <-sC
    //do something with `s`. We print but we may want to use it in a `func(s)`
    print(s)
    //after a while we do soemthing with `c`
    c := <-cC

    print(c)
}

func getS(sC chan string) {
    s := " simple completed \n"
    sC <- s
    print("sent s back so that main can read it too")
    sC <- s
}

func getC(sC chan string, cC chan string) {
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    //we do some complex stuff
    print("complex is not complicated\n")
    //Now  we need the simple value so we try wait for the s channel.
    s := <-sC


    c := s + " more "
    cC <- c //send complex value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the synchronization. Using a sleep may solve the problem. When you send a value on a channel, it should be received on the other end or else it will show deadlock error.
package main

```
import "sync"
import "time"
import "fmt"

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {
    sC := make(chan string)
    wg.Add(1)
    go getS(sC)

    cC := make(chan string)
    wg.Add(1)
    go getC(sC, cC)

    time.Sleep(1 * time.Millisecond)
    select {
    case s := <-sC:
        print(s)

    case c := <-cC:
        print(c)
    }

    wg.Wait()
}
func getS(sC chan string) {
    defer wg.Done()
    s := " simple completed "
    fmt.Println(s)
    sC <- s
}

func getC(sC chan string, cC chan string) {
    defer wg.Done()
    fmt.Println("complex is not complicated\n")
    s := <-sC
    c := s + " more "
    cC <- c //send complex value
}
```